# Any way to launch Siri programmatically in iOS 12 / 13 using private APIs or BLE?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, siri

I am trying to build a prototype where I want to launch Siri every time I press a button (on my guitar). I have been looking into using private APIs but haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any pointers? In particular I looking into long pressing the lock button programmatically in order to launch Siri.

Comment: You can do it via Bluetooth if you have hardware that implements the Handsfree Profile.  See chapter 15 in https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf. You would need your own hardware to do this.  You can't do it on the phone apart from long press on home (Side on iPhone X) or "Hey Siri"

Comment: Very cool, thank you for the link. Any pointers on the code to trigger that long press on home (sinde on iphone X) programatically? I have been looking into the private api's but headers change constantly and can't see anything for iOS 12+